# Sharing xmlhttpObject 'progress' and 'load' Event handlers between two functions (no JQUERY)

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am uploading a video file using an API to a third party server.

I have an upload function `vim.uploadVidFile` which has 'progress' and 'load' event listeners.  If there is internet connectivity loss, I have a second function which uploads the file from where the upload got disrupted, `vim.resumeUpload`. This functions shares the same 'progress' and 'load' event listeners.

The issue I have is that the 'progress', and 'load' event listeners are still registering the original size of the file to be uploaded rather than the new (`originalFileSize` - `fileSizeAlreadyUploadedToServer`).  This affects my progress bar and the fact that instead of uploading from where I left off, it re-uploads the entire file again.

With reference to  vim.uploadProgres I found that In the console:

```
console.log('ORIGINAL_e.total: '+ e.total) == console.log('adjusted_e.total: '+ e.total);
```

`vim.uploadVidFile` function:

```
vim.uploadVidFile = function(){
    console.log('uploadVidFile()...');

    // GET VIDEO FILE
    var input = document.getElementById('vidInput');
    var vidFile = input.files[0];

    var xmh = new XMLHttpRequest;

    // SET EVENT LISTENERS
    xmh.upload.addEventListener('progress', vim.uploadProgres, false);
    xmh.addEventListener('load', vim.uploadComplete, false);
    xmh.addEventListener('error', vim.uploadError, false);

    xmh.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(this.readyState == this.HEADERS_RECEIVED){
            console.log('RESPONSE HEADERS: ' + xmh.getAllResponseHeaders());
        }
    }
    xmh.open('PUT', vim.upload_link_secure);
    xmh.send(vidFile);
}
```

`vim.resumeUpload` function:

```
vim.resumeUpload = function(stringArgument){
    console.log('vim.resumeUpload() ...');
    console.log('stringArgument: ' + stringArgument);

    // GET VIDEO FILE
    var input = document.getElementById('vidInput');
    var vidFile = input.files[0];

    var xmh = new XMLHttpRequest;

    // SET EVENT LISTENERS
    // SET EVENT LISTENERS
    xmh.upload.addEventListener('progress', vim.uploadProgres, false);
    xmh.addEventListener('load', vim.uploadComplete, false);
    xmh.addEventListener('error', vim.uploadError, false);

    xmh.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xmh.readyState == xmh.HEADERS_RECEIVED){
            console.log('VERIFY RESPONSE HEADERS222: ' + xmh.getAllResponseHeaders());
            console.log('getResponseHeader(\'Content-Range\')222' + xmh.getResponseHeader("Range"));
        }
    }
    xmh.open('PUT', vim.upload_link_secure);
    xmh.setRequestHeader('Content-Range', stringArgument);
    xmh.send(vidFile);

}
```

'progress' eventListener:

```
// vim.bytesUploaded - bytes already uploaded to the server

vim.uploadProgres = function(e){
    console.log('bytesUploaded_CONSTANT: '+ vim.bytesUploaded);

    if(vim.bytesUploaded == 0){
        var percent = (e.loaded/e.total) * 100;
        document.getElementById('span_fill').setAttribute('style', 'width: '+ percent + '%');
        document.getElementById('p_status').innerHTML= Math.round(percent) + '%'; 

        console.log('e.loaded: '+e.loaded);
        console.log('e.total: '+e.total);
    }else{

        console.log('ORIGINAL_e.total: '+ e.total);
        e.total = e.total - vim.bytesUploaded;

        var percent = (e.loaded/e.total) * 100;
        document.getElementById('span_fill').setAttribute('style', 'width: '+ percent + '%');
        document.getElementById('p_status').innerHTML= Math.round(percent) + '%';
        console.log('adjusted_e.total: '+ e.total);
        console.log('uploadedFoFar: ' + uploadedFoFar);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've re-phrased it

Comment: Pretty sure `xmh.addEventListener` should be `xhm.upload.addEventListener` instead. Try changing those things related to the upload. If you're using XMLHttpRequest Level 2, you might as well not test for `xhm.readyState` and the like, you can just use `xhm.onload = function(){}`.

Comment: Your `uploadVidFile` and `resumeUpload` functions are virtually identical. As a first step, you should collapse them into one. Next, get rid of the "separate" event handlers, just define them inline in the single "upload" function you have now. Third, I would tack the number of uploaded bytes onto the `file` object directly (`vidFile.uploaded = vidFile.uploaded || 0`) so you have the offset available on resume. Lastly, you should be able to use [`Blob.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/slice) on the `vidFile` to pick the proper chunk for the resume.